# How can I change identity property in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has no identity column. I want to change a column's identity specification, but SQL Server 2008 doesn't allow that. So, how can I change identity property in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: what do you mean doesn't allow?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column, ideally you want to use int or bigint

Answer (score 13, accepted):

under tools-->options-->designers-->table and database designers

uncheck prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a new column as an identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD COLUMN [columnName] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
GO
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([columnName])
```

If you're trying to use the SQL 2008 designer, there is a setting you have to disable so that the designer can drop and recreate the table.

Comment: @Jon Correct you are, fixed.